# Implementing a generic class and choosing a collection based on a type

Tags: c#, generics

[In this topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32922880/generic-class-to-return-particular-set-of-data-depending-on-type/32922910#32922910) I have aksed for help to sort out an error while creating a generic class whose method can return a different collection given a type. I received the answer and working solution but I have a feeling the problem is not sorted in proper way. That is why I came here for a review.

The reason for having a generic class is is that I use DI and pass either `DbContext` to collect data from a database or another Object to "collect" data from collections. The DI is done in the main `Program`. The interface is generic to handle `DbContext` and then fetching particular collection given a type: `DbContext.Set<>()`. The `FetchDataFromCollection` is also generic, so is `FetchDataFromDatabase` because this is how `DbCOntext` works.

Is there any other way to sort it out and for instance avoid if ... else blocks? I was thinking to make another class `ModelBase`, inherits from it into concrete implementations, which would return a specific collection and inject such class into `FetchFromCollection` but then I would have to make this decition by myself which class to inject to get proper collection in `FetchFromCollection`. What I would have is a method which would decide to return a particular collection given a type.

I don't know if it's possible. Below are the three program components.

**`IFetchData`:**

```
public interface IFetchData<TEntity>
{
    IEnumerable<TEntity> GetItems();
}
```

Then I have created these two classes:

**`FetchFromDatabase`:**

```
public class FetchFromDatabase<TEntity> : IFetchData<TEntity>
    where TEntity : class
{
    private readonly MainDBContextBase context;

    public FetchFromDatabase(MainDBContextBase context)
    {
        if (context == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("DB context");
        this.context = context;
    }

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetItems()
    {
        return context.Set<TEntity>();
    }
}
```

**`FetchFromCollection`:**

```
public class FetchFromCollection<TEntity> : IFetchData<TEntity>
    where TEntity : class
{
    // ModelBase<TEntity> models;

    private readonly InitializeComponents components;
    private ModelModules modules;
    private ModelSpecializations specializations;
    private ModelTeachers teachers;
    private ModelStudents students;

    public FetchFromCollection(InitializeComponents components)
    {
        if (components == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Context");
        this.components = components;
    }

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetItems()
    {
        if (typeof(TEntity) == typeof(Module))
        {
            if (modules == null)
                modules = new ModelModules(components);
            return (IEnumerable<TEntity>)modules.Set();
        }
        if (typeof(TEntity) == typeof(Specialization))
        {
            if (specializations == null)
                specializations = new ModelSpecializations(components);
            return (IEnumerable<TEntity>)specializations.Set();
        }
        if (typeof(TEntity) == typeof(Module))
        {
            if (teachers == null)
                teachers = new ModelTeachers(components);
            return (IEnumerable<TEntity>)teachers.Set();
        }
        else
        {
            if (students == null)
                students = new ModelStudents(components);
            return (IEnumerable<TEntity>)students.Set();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would using a generic *method* instead of a generic class help? I'm unclear on what it is that you're *really* trying to accomplish.

Comment: `DbContext` has a method called `DbSet<> Set<>()`. By providing a type, we query for records in a table. The object somehow has its intelligence to in decision which table to query. I tried to do this for collection in memory.

Comment: I don't know if a generic method would work. I inject one of these objects to another object which later present queried data. Technically the class `Fetch...` is to encapsulate the method `IEnumerable<TEntity> GetItems()` because this is how I belive the Dependency Injection work; we define a field of an interface type and later inject objects which use common methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you could just mirror the way `FetchFromDatabase` is implemented. First thing you will need is a something like a DbContext, but for collections. This new class should be capable of returning an `IEnumerable<TEntity>` for any `TEntity` defined -- just like `DbContext`.

```
public class CollectionContext
{
    private Dictionary<Type, object> _cache;

    public CollectionContext()
    {
        _cache = new Dictionary<Type, object>();
    }

    public void AddCollection<TEntity>(IEnumerable<TEntity> collection)
    {
        _cache.Add(typeof(TEntity), collection);
    }

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> Set<TEntity>()
    {
        return (IEnumerable<TEntity>)_cache[typeof(TEntity)];
    }
}
```

Now `FetchFromCollection` can be implemented exactly like `FetchFromDatabase`, with exception of the type used in the constructor.

```
public class FetchFromCollection<TEntity> : IFetchData<TEntity>
where TEntity : class
{
    private readonly CollectionContext context;

    public FetchFromCollection(CollectionContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Collection context");
        this.context = context;
    }

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetItems()
    {
        return context.Set<TEntity>();
    }
}
```

This is how you'd use it.

```
// Load up all your collections
var context = new CollectionContext();
context.AddCollection<Module>(new ModelModules(components).Set());
context.AddCollection<Specialization>(new ModelSpecializations(components).Set());
context.AddCollection<Teacher>(new ModelTeachers(components).Set());

// Example usage
IFetchData<Module> modules = new FetchFromCollection<Module>(context);
```

I think you can further improve on your design by getting rid of the generic type parameter on `FetchFromDatabase` and `FetchFromCollection`. Each of these classes is capable of pulling any `TEntity` out of their contexts'. By making this change you'd only need to have one instance of `FetchFromDatabase` and `FetchFromCollection` for your entire application, instead of one instance of each for every `TEntity`. You can just move the generic type parameter down to `GetItems()`. This same change would need to be made to `IFetchData`. Here is an example for `FetchFromCollection`, the same change can be made to `FetchFromDatabase`:

```
public class FetchFromCollection : IFetchData
   {
    private readonly CollectionContext context;

    public FetchFromCollection(CollectionContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Collection context");
        this.context = context;
    }

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetItems<TEntity>()
    {
        return context.Set<TEntity>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man. I really appreciate your effort. It did not occur to me that I could use `Dictionary<Type, Object>`. Somehow, I did not imagine that the `Type` could be a value and consequently a key for a dictionary. Also, thanks for pointing out the issue about having a generic class :) It's really valueable answer to me! I would give you more than one vote if I could.

Comment: Hello again. I did try to improve the function `FetchFromCollection` to avoid the generic type. I found problem here. First I removed it from class, so compiler complained as Interface is generic. I removed a generic type from the interface but then a return type, `IEnumerable<TEntity>`, has to be still generic. So I cannot fulfil with this improvement :/

Comment: It should work if you make the method generic. It should be GetItems<TEntity>() like in my example. Also make sure you change `IFetchData` interface.

Comment: @MikeHixon I am probably missing something very trivial here. Currently, the interface is generic because the method `IEnumerable<TEntity> GetItems()` returns collection of items of the type `TEntity`. if I remove `<TEentity>` from interface, I don't know what type should `GetItems()` return then.

Comment: You can have a method that is generic without the whole class being generic. Try using the FetchFromCollection class just as I have it above, but without the interface. Checkout how it works, then add the interface back when you understand it.

Comment: I think generic method inheriting from a generic interface works better in my particular case. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing the same thing as Mike, but went one step further:

## Removed classes

Getting the items into `CollectionContext` can be simplified, there is no need for the `ModuleXXX`-classes. The different items can be added directly:

```
context = new CollectionContext();
context.Append(new[] {new Module()});
context.Append(new[] {new Specialization()});
context.Append(new[] {new Teacher()});
context.Append(new[] {new Student()});
```

The usage is identical to Mike's, but I added a static `GetItem` method to force the code to use the `IFetchData` interface:

```
var items = GetItems(new FetchFromCollection<Module>(context));

static IEnumerable<T> GetItems<T>(IFetchData<T> fetcher)
{
    return fetcher.GetItems();
}
```

By the way, I suspect you are not into Test Driven Development? I suggest you give it a try. Just by writing the expected client side code using `FetchFromCollection` would address some of your questions.

## CollectionContext

```
public class CollectionContext
{
    readonly List<object> collection = new List<object>();

    public void Append(IEnumerable<object> modules)
    {
        collection.AddRange(modules);
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> Set<T>()
    {
        return collection.OfType<T>();
    }
}
```

## Tests

```
[TestFixture]
public class Given_some_known_collections
{
    CollectionContext context;

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        context = new CollectionContext();
        context.Append(new[] {new Module()});
        context.Append(new[] {new Specialization()});
        context.Append(new[] {new Teacher()});
        context.Append(new[] {new Student()});
    }

    [Test]
    public void Get_modules()
    {
        var items = GetItems(new FetchFromCollection<Module>(context));
        Assert.That(items.Count(), Is.EqualTo(1));
    }

    [Test]
    public void Get_specializations()
    {
        var items = GetItems(new FetchFromCollection<Specialization>(context));
        Assert.That(items.Count(), Is.EqualTo(1));
    }

    [Test]
    public void Get_teachers()
    {
        var items = GetItems(new FetchFromCollection<Teacher>(context));
        Assert.That(items.Count(), Is.EqualTo(1));
    }

    [Test]
    public void Get_students()
    {
        var items = GetItems(new FetchFromCollection<Student>(context));
        Assert.That(items.Count(), Is.EqualTo(1));
    }

    static IEnumerable<T> GetItems<T>(IFetchData<T> fetcher)
    {
        return fetcher.GetItems();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am new to TDD and it's not the first time I've been suggested to use tests. Perhaps the time to to start with it is now :)